# Maintain SVG Aspect Ratio and Resize Parent

Tags: html, css, svg, layout, aspect-ratio

I have three `<svg>`s side by side in a container `<div>` (inside a container `<div>`).

Each `<svg>` should always take up one-third of its immediate parent's width ***and*** have a height equal to its width.

This means that as the window is resized, and the `<svg>`s' width become smaller or larger, so should their heights, and so should the height of the container `<div>`.

```css
#container { 
    background-color: grey;
}

.svg-wrapper {
   background-color: red;
   display: inline;
}

svg {
  background-color: white;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="svg-wrapper" id="sw1">
        <svg id="svg1"></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="svg-wrapper" id="sw2">
        <svg id="svg2"></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="svg-wrapper" id="sw3">
        <svg id="svg3"></svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the advice of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441480/2809263) answer, I tried adding `.svg-wrapper { padding-bottom: 100% }`, but to no avail.

**EDIT:** Basically, two conditions should always be satisfied:

1. The three `<svg>`s should always be square: their height is equal to their width
2. The width of each `<svg>` should be one-third of their parent's width.

When the width of the parent changes because the page is resized, the width of each `<svg>` should also change so that it remains one-third of the parent. The height of each `<svg>` should also change, by the same amount, so height and width are always equal.

**Voted to Close:** My question was really the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css?noredirect=1&lq=1). I didn't see the part of [Web_Designer's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441480/2809263) that specified making the position of the wrapper relative and the position of the inside-div absolute.

Comment: I can't understand your question properly. Would you explain a bit more.

Comment: You can't maintain the aspect ratio of something and constrain both the width and the height, something has to give. What is it and in what way?

Comment: @RobertLongson I mean to constrain the aspect ratio (it should always be 1:1) and the width (it should always be 1/3 of the container). The height should always be equal to the width, and vary with the width

Comment: @hunzaboy Please see my edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

**See the Solution Below**

```css
#container { 
    background-color: grey;
}
 *{
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
.svg-wrapper {
   background-color: red;
   width: 33.33%;
  float:left;
}

svg {
  background-color: white;
  max-width:100%;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="svg-wrapper" id="sw1">
        <svg id="svg1"></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="svg-wrapper" id="sw2">
        <svg id="svg2"></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="svg-wrapper" id="sw3">
        <svg id="svg3"></svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to maintain the aspect ratio.